# How to conditionally format highest value of multiple ranges

Tags: google-sheets, formatting, max, gs-conditional-formatting

I'm trying to use conditional formatting to highlight the maximum value over multiple ranges. That is, find the one highest value in said ranges and highlight all instances of it. I have been able to use conditional formatting to highlight the highest number of one column, but not over multiple.

The ranges in question are: `G3:G13,J3:J13,M3:M13,P3:P13,S3:S13,V3:V13`

[Screenshot of the spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBhvD.png)

The versions I have tried either highlight every value in the first row, multiple values but not the highest one, or nothing at all.

An alternative is to use a MAX function and place that value in another cell (the little 4 in the bottom right corner) and use conditional formatting based on that value. However, it's not a particularly elegant solution nor have I been able to make that work properly.

I am using New Google Sheets and am familiar with custom formatting and custom formulas for doing so.

Comment: Found the way to properly format it using the additional cell. In this case: `=G3=$V$15` for range 

`G3:G13, J3:J13, M3:M13, P3:P13, S3:S13, V3:V13`


or `=[first cell in range]=[cell with the value using $]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use Conditional Formatting Custom Formula.

Set Apply to Range

G3:G13,J3:J13,M3:M13,P3:P13,S3:S13,V3:V13

Enter in Custom Formula is

=G3=(max($G$3:$G$13,$J$3:$J$13,$M$3:$M$13,$P$3:$P$13,$S$3:$S$13,$V$3:$V$13))

Pick your formatting style.
You may have to scroll down the Format cells if menu to find Custom Formula.

Comment: That would only work for G3 through G13 though. I want a custom formula that checks all the ranges for the one common max value (in this situation, 4) and formats any cells with that value.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question. I changed the answer. Try it now.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: What does the =G3= means at the start? I'm trying to highlight the max of non-consecutive cells